# How to write a batch file to find combinations of variables

Tags: batch-file, combinations

I'm trying to teach myself a bit of basic coding this summer, and I'm trying to write a program for myself and my friend. We both like music, and every once in a while we mix songs. Although it takes more than just finding good song combinations, I wanted to write a program that helps us to remember combinations.

Practically I wanted to put all song combinations in a .txt file manually, for example:

```
song1 song2
song1 song3
song2 song4
song4 song3
```

Then I wanted to create a batch that can find every combination with e.g. song2 and give a list of this. When my input is song2 in this case, I want my output to be:

```
song1
song4
```

My attempt at this is shown below. Note that I've already written the script to create the two .txt files. I'm sorry if it's sloppy. I know nothing about coding apart from what I've learned online.

```
   :list
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    cls
    echo With what track would you like to start?
    echo.
    Set /P "track= "
    FIND /I "%track%" combinations.txt >> resultstemp.txt
    echo.
    echo --- GOES WITH: ---
    echo.
    echo.
    attrib -h -s %~dp0\resultstemp.txt
    type %~dp0\resultstemp.txt
    break>resultstemp.txt
    attrib +h +s %~dp0\resultstemp.txt
    echo.
    echo.
    pause
    cls
```

The current output is:

```
With what track would you like to start?

song2

---goes with: ---

------------Combinations.txt
song2 song1
song4 song2

Press any key to coninue . . .
```

While I want it to be:

```
With what track would you like to start?

song2

---goes with: ---


song1
song4

Press any key to continue...
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: I modified the code in order to manage songs that may include spaces.

```
@echo off
setlocal

echo With what track would you like to start?
echo/
set /P "track="
echo/
echo ---goes with: ---
echo/
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('FIND /I "%track%" ^< combinations.txt') do (
   for %%b in (%%a) do (
      if "%%~b" neq "%track%" echo %%~b
   )
)
```

If you have any question about this code, you may remove the `@echo off` line to see what exactly is executed...

For example, using this data in the input file:

```
"Love me do Insomnia" song2
"Love me do Insomnia" "Another song"
song2 song4
song4 "Another song"
```

... this is an output example:

```
C:\Users\Antonio\test> test.bat
With what track would you like to start?

song2

---goes with: ---

Love me do Insomnia
song4

C:\Users\Antonio\test> test.bat
With what track would you like to start?

Another song

---goes with: ---

Love me do Insomnia
song4
```

Comment: This seems to work great, until the songs contain spaces. When I write "Love me do Insomnia" (or whatever), I get love, me and do seperately when I give insomnia as input. Any way to bypass this in your method?